# How to position an image relative to text

Tags: css

tldr; How do I position a picture so it moves propotional to the text moving when a window is resized.

In my example here I have used absoulute position to make it look good in 1920x1080 I would like it to follow the text when I resize the window.

Go to nordicreservation.com and resize it on the x axis to see what I mean if you don't understand my question.

Apriciate any help I can get here as I am rather new to this and just trying to create a website for my father.

```
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h1 style="color: #06068E;">HJEMMEDATAHJELPEN</h1>
    <p>Hjemmedatahjelpen sikter seg inn på å komme hjem til folk i Nittedal og bistå med teknisk assistanse.
    <img src="myimmage.jpg" alt="Bilde"" width="143" height="200" style="position: absolute; TOP: 116px; LEFT: 1120px;" longdesc="http://www.hjemmedatahjelpen.no/Johannes" >
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So tell us: what _exactly_ do you mean by "to follow the text when I resize the window"?

Comment: Your example--nordicreservation.com--doesn't seem to resolve.  Perhaps you could make the question more clear by displaying a few screenshots of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are after or not but from the website you mention you could try put a div around your list, place the image in the div, float the list left and image right and put a clear div at the bottom.  Something like this...

```
<div>
  <ol type="1" style="float:left;font-size:14px;">
    <li> Rydde i PC´en for å få den til å gå raskere. </li>
    <li> Lage enkle bruksanvisninger på å gjøre ting </li>
    <li> Lage enkle oppsett som gjør ting enklere som snarveier og annet. </li>
    <li> Hjelpe med å konfigurere mobilen. </li>
    <li> Oppsett av e-post, Internett oa. </li>
    <li> Støtte til iPad, iMac og iPhone oa. </li>
    <li> Støtte til Windows, Word, Excel oa. </li>
    <li> Hvordan enkelt redigere video, organisere bilder oa. </li> 
  </ol>
  <img src="johannes.jpg" alt="Bilde" width="143" height="200" style="float:right;" longdesc="http://www.hjemmedatahjelpen.no/Johannes" />
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>                                                                                                                                                
</div>
```

Comment: This would work if I can make it be slightly to the right of the text instead of way over on the right side of the screen.

Comment: Try put `float:left` on the `img` instead of `float:right` (that will put it closer to the list).  You can then add `margin-left:20px` to the style of the img to control the gap more precisely.

Comment: This is very close to how I wanted it, would just like to have it a little bit up. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use percentage for this, like: 
`margin-left: 80%;`

This is adjust in any size of screen.

Comment: I allready tried that, and the picture moves at a difrent rate then the text. Updated the website to 80% if you want to take a look.

Comment: Using `position: absolute;` will not help you! Try to remove that inline CSS from the image and create a class for it in CSS. Examples: `.image-content {margin-left: 80%;}` and in the img tag use `<img src="img.jpg" class="image-content">`. You can start editing from this. :)

Comment: Doing: position: relative; TOP: 116px; LEFT: 80%; I get the x axis to be like I wanted to, but sadly it is now not where I want it to on the y axis

Comment: Use percentage in top too!

Comment: It just goes relative to bellow the text.